# how to upload image file as binary to azure storage account in python

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage

I have this code below which as of now does not upload image file that it receives from the client. It receives the image file as an UploadFile instance. I have read that using the read() method will convert the file to bytes and that way I will be able to upload, but that didn't work for me. Not sure that what I am doing wrong here.

```
async def resolve_fileUpload(_, info, file):
    print(f"File - {type(file)}")

    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(
        '4160000000')
    if not container_client.exists():
        container_client.create_container()

    with open(file, "rb") as file:
        result = container_client.upload_blob(
            name='avatar', data=file.read())
    return {
        "status": 200,
        "error": "",
        "fileUrl": "www.test.com"
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated as I am stuck on this for days now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results.**

You can follow the below code to achieve your goal to upload images to Azure blob storage.

**`demo.py`**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from io import BytesIO

app = FastAPI()

# Initialize Azure Storage Blob Service Client
connection_string = "your-connection-string"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

@app.post("/upload")
async def resolve_fileUpload(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    print(f"File - {type(file)}")

    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client('test')
    if not container_client.exists():
        container_client.create_container()

    file_bytes = await file.read()  # Read the file content as bytes

    with BytesIO(file_bytes) as byte_stream:
        result = container_client.upload_blob(name='avatar/avatar.jpg', data=byte_stream)

    return {
        "status": 200,
        "error": "",
        "fileUrl": "www.test.com"
    }
```

Install uvicorn using **`pip install uvicorn`**

Run the above file using `uvicorn <yourpythonfilename>:app --reload`

Once you execute with above command in your terminal you will get like below.

[image]

Now, create another python file **`test.py`** with the below code:

```
    import requests
    
    url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload"
    files = {'file': open('path/to/file.jpg', 'rb')}
    response = requests.post(url, files=files)
    print(response.status_code, response.text)
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you Venkatesan for this detailed post.

Answer (score 0):

MS Docs indicate that `upload_blob` needs a file I/O object, not the actual bytes. From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-upload-python#upload-a-block-blob-from-a-local-file-path

Try changing your code to just pass the Reader object, instead of the data.

```
with open(file, "rb") as file:
    result = container_client.upload_blob(
        name='avatar', data=file)
```